# How to pass arguments from Dart to Cloud functions written in Typescript and it also gives me error code UNAUTHENTICATED

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

Dart function (passing `token` to `sendToDevice`):

```
Future<void> _sendNotification() async {
  CloudFunctions functions = CloudFunctions.instance;
  HttpsCallable callable = functions.getHttpsCallable(functionName: "sendToDevice");

  callable.call({
    'token': await FirebaseMessaging().getToken(),
  });
}
```

`index.ts` file where I have defined `sendToDevice` method.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

const fcm = admin.messaging();

export const sendToDevice = functions.firestore
  .document('users/uid')
  .onCreate(async snapshot => {

    const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'Dummy title',
        body: `Dummy body`,
        click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
      }
    };

    return fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, payload); // how to get tokens here passed from above function?
  }
);
```

---

Questions:

1. How can I receive tokens passed from my Dart function `_sendNotification` to Typescript's `sendToDevice` function.
2. When I was directly passing tokens inside `index.ts` file, I was getting this exception:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(functionsError, Cloud function failed with exception., {code: UNAUTHENTICATED, details: null, message: UNAUTHENTICATED})

Can anyone please explain if I am supposed to authenticate something here? The command `firebase login` shows I am already signed in. I am very new to Typescript so please bear with these stupid questions.

Comment: Are you trying to get this function triggered when a new document is created? If so, why are you calling the same function from client side again?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Yes actually that's what I am looking for, since I have no idea bout typscript, not sure what this code is doing.

Comment: So then you should store your device tokens on your db to query them when function is triggered, not passing them from the client side to the function. The flow should be like this: a document is created -> cloud function is triggered -> function queries tokens from db -> it pushes notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a database trigger, what you should do is create a callable function as shown below

```
exports.sendToDevice = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
        notification: {
          title: 'Dummy title',
          body: `Dummy body`,
          click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
        }
      };

      return await fcm.sendToDevice(data.token, payload);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Flutter side of code seems right, what's wrong is on the Cloud Function.

The `sendToDevice` function is not a callable function. It is a [Cloud Firestore Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events), it is only meant to be automatically called whenever a document matches `users/{uid}` is created.

Instead, you'll want to create a [Callable Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), see below

```js
export const sendToDevice = functions.https
  .onCall(async (data) => {
    const { token } = data; // Data is what you'd send from callable.call

    const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'Dummy title',
        body: `Dummy body`,
        click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
      }
    };

    return fcm.sendToDevice(token, payload);
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am using your code, but I getting this error `Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(functionsError, Cloud function failed with exception., {code: UNAUTHENTICATED, details: null, message: UNAUTHENTICATED})`, I double checked my `token` isn't `null`.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest a few debugging steps just to be sure, first, double check that your credentials are on the same Firebase project. Secondly, remove the FCM portion just to test the function is called. Access to your Firebase console and try to send a notification using the token you've gotten. You might also want to see what's logging on the Cloud Function Dashboard

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to mention here:

1st The function used in 'getHttpsCallable' must be triggered by https trigger (reference [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_functions/latest/cloud_functions/CloudFunctions/getHttpsCallable.html)). Here we have a function triggered by firestore document create, so it won't work.

2nd You do not have parameter of your function, but you call it with parameters. If you need example of calling cloud function with parameter you can find it on [pud.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions#-example-tab-)

3rd I do not have at the moment possibility to play with it, but I think that if you implement https triggered function with `token` parameter you should be able to pass this parameter.

I hope it will help!

UPDATE:

According to [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) https triggered function has to be created with `functions.https`. There is a nice example in the doc.  To function triggered this way you can add request body when you can pass needed data.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but sorry they weren't quite useful. For instance, you said `getHttpsCallable` should be triggered by `https`, can you please tell me where inside my code am I supposed to make that change?

Comment: Second, the example you provided doesn't reveal how they are handling passed parameter inside `index.js` file, they only provided Dart code and my code resembles to it, can you please tell me how can I do that inside `index.js`?

Comment: Sorry @iKeepChangingName I thought it's clear, I added the reference to Google Documentation, I hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

This answer might not solve your problem but will give you a few things to try, and you'll learn along the way. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get the callable https working with the emulator. I'll probably submit a github issue about it soon. The flutter app keeps just getting different types of undecipherable errors depending on the local URL I try.

---

It's good that you've fixed one of the problems: you were using document trigger (`onCreate`) instead of a https callable. But now, you're running a https callable and the Flutter apps needs to communicate with your functions directly. In the future, you could run the functions emulator locally, and do a lot of `console.log`'ing to understand if it actually gets triggered.

I have a few questions/ things you can try:

- Is your user logged in the flutter app? `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` will tell you.
- Does this problem happen on both iOS and android?
- Add some logs to your typescript function, and redeploy. Read the latest logs through StackDriver or in terminal, `firebase functions:log --only sendToDevice`. (sendToDevice is your callable function name)
- Are you deploying to the cloud and testing with the latest deployment of your functions? You can actually test with a [local emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype). On Android, the url is `10.0.2.2:5001` as shown above. You also need to run `adb reverse tcp:5001 tcp:5001` in the terminal. If you're on the cloud, then `firebase login` doesn't matter, *I think* your functions should already have the credentials.

To call the emulator https callable:

```
HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance
    .useFunctionsEmulator(origin: "http://10.0.2.2:5001")
    .getHttpsCallable(functionName: "sendToDevice");
```

And iOS you need to follow the solution [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38452).

One mistake I spotted. You should at least do `return await fcm.sendToDevice()` where you wait for the promise to resolve, because otherwise the cloud function runtime will terminate your function before it resolves. Alternatively, for debugging, instead of returning `sendToDevice` in your cloud function, you could have saved it into a variable, and `console.log`'d it. You would see its actually a promise (or a Future in dart's terminology) that hadn't actually resolved.

```
 const messagingDevicesResponse: admin.messaging.MessagingDevicesResponse = await fcm.sendToDevice(
    token,
    payload
  );
  console.log({ messagingDevicesResponse });
  return;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Make the function public

The problem is asociated with credentials. You can change the security policy of the CF and sheck if the problem is fixed. Se how to manage permisions on CF [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam)